# abt oracle procedure agv and deleting the csv file from procedures of oracle

Tags: oracle

Hi can u give me the info abt how can we pass the arg to the oracle procedures

how can i delete the csv file from oracle procedures

Answer (score 0):

You can use the UTL_FILE package to interact with system files located on the server. You should read the [documentation](http://download-uk.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/u_file.htm#BABGGEDF) to learn how to setup your environment. Once you have created the directory you want to access in oracle (here named `DIR`), this [command](http://download-uk.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/u_file.htm#i1003602) will delete a file:

```
utl_file.fremove('DIR', 'FILE_NAME');
```

Comment: It should be pointed out that UTL_FILE files are located on the database server itself, not client-side.

Comment: @Thilo: you're right, I updated my answer. It should be clearer now, thanks.